# Avoid adding source and resource files to every target

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a project with multiple targets sharing most of their functionality.  I have to add new targets often and I want to make it as quick as possible. Is there a way to not have to add all the libraries, sources code files and resources to every newly added target? I need some sort of parent target/project which can hold the .h, .m files as well as .string, .bundle, .xib etc. This way the new target can only define its name and icons and a few other minor details.

Comment: Projects can contain sub-projects or reference frameworks.  Do either of those approaches work for you?  (If not, why not?)

Comment: What is wrong with the Edit>Duplicate way ?

Comment: @PhillipMills a subproject approach could work for me. What is the difference between keeping all these in a subproject vs having a target which contains all of the files and adding that target as a dependency to the newly added ones?

Comment: @A-Live duplicating targets does exactly that - duplicates. This means that if I need to make a change later I have to add/remove a given file from all targets.

Comment: I find it easier to look at the subproject to find out what's in it than I would to check which things belong to a target.  YMMV.